# How to setup a 6TB HD on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, fdisk, parted

I just bought a 6TB HD from WD and I cannot make bigger partitions than 2TB. I looked up in some tutorials like [this one](http://dev-random.net/creating-mounting-partition-lager-2-tb-linux/), but I still have the problem that `fdisk`, `parted` and `lsblk` display that there are only 2 TB space on the harddisk without partitions.

For example:

```
(parted) print                                                            

Model: ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdi: 2199GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: gpt  


GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1 Partition table scan: 
MBR: protective BSD: not present APM: not present GPT: present Found valid GPT with protective MBR; 
using GPT. Disk /dev/sdi: 4294967294 sectors, 2.0 TiB Logical sector size: 512 bytes 
Disk identifier (GUID): 5347B4F4-DFDD-446B-B2E2-8E8D66886DEC Partition table holds up to 128 entries 
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4294967260 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries 
Total free space is 4294967227 sectors (2.0 TiB)
```

Does somebody know where the problem could be?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What does gdisk show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdi` It almost has to be 512/4k sectors. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/

Comment: GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdi: 4294967294 sectors, 2.0 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 5347B4F4-DFDD-446B-B2E2-8E8D66886DEC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4294967260
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4294967227 sectors (2.0 TiB)

Comment: Please post above and add code tags to preserve formatting, not really readable, but seems like it also thinks it is 2TiB? How did you originally partition? Old versions of fdisk did not work with gpt. Best to only use gdisk or parted/gparted, but not old versions. What does BIOS/UEFI say? Is this an external drive. Many older USB caddies do not support gpt or larger drives and that could be issue.

Comment: It's an internal drive, and until now there were never a partition in use. BIOS/UEFI says also 2TB, so the problem seems to come from the Hardware i think (?). Where do I see, if this is a setting-issue or not supportet by my Hardware? I am using a Z800 Workstation from HP: [http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01709726]

Answer (score 2):

Use GPT partitioning instead of dos to enable partition size to be larger than 2T.

Comment: GPT partitioning is used on my disk, as I understand. Changing had no effect...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my problem without knowing exactly where the problem was. ([Link](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/festplatte-wird-nur-als-2tb-angezeigt/) to the German forum). Seams that there are multiple controllers for hard-disks on my Mainboard, and the one that the HD was connected, did not support bigger hard-disks than 2TB. Fortunately the other controller, supported bigger sizes. So with changing the connectors it was possible for me, to use all hard-disks in the full range. Thank you for your help!